# why i get the "IndexError: list index out of range" error?

Tags: python, indexing, range

i want to replace some values with new values in a text-file. I have a list with old values (c) and a list with new values(iteml).
my code is:

```
def write_file(self):

   iteml=[]
   for row in range(152):
             item=self.model.item(row,1)
             item.text()
             text=str(item.text())
             iteml.append(text)



   alt=open("file","r")
   neu=open("newfile","w")

   x=0
   for line in alt:
      if line[0] == "|":
           neu.write(line)
      if line[0] != "|":
           line=line.replace(c[x],iteml[x])
           x=x+1
           neu.write(line)
```

c[] is defined global, and is 152 elements long, so i have no idea why at "line=line.replace(c[x],iteml[x])" the indexerror appears.

when i use "print(c)" or "print(iteml)" i get the whole list... where is my fail?

Comment: why dont you print x on the line before your error and see what its value is ... Im guessing it is larger than the array size ...

Comment: The count of lines in the read file is bigger than 152, isn't it?

Comment: yeah, you`re right. if i print x just before the error, x counts to 152. yep, the read file is has more than 152 lines.

Comment: @Deck: I dont get it, why my x counts itself up to 152, befor even start to replace... can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

*C[]* may be 152 elements long, but as you are iterating over *alt* and incrementing *x* by one in every iteration, it's possible that your loop is doing more than 152 iterations, because it depends on the length of alt.

A possible solution would be adding and if statement at the end of the loop:

```
if (x == 152):
     break
```

So whenever your loop reach iteration num 152, it will finish its execution and you won't have any IndexError.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is because the number of items in each is not necessarily equal so you shouldn't hard-code a number like `152`.

You posted about this same code earlier.

Try working through my answer from that question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20217097/how-to-ignore-following-characters-in-a-line/20217594#20217594